# Retrieve old facebook event covers using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been making events since 2011 and I'm trying to retrieve old event covers for archival purposes. Unfortunately I can't see covers before around Feb 2013. I assume the API terms changed around then, but I fear the images are lost forever.

After some research I think the field was picture,pic,pic_big but sadly nothing is returned in Facebook API explorer. Does anyone have any ideas? I assume Facebook has just got rid of them.

Thanks, I appreciate any help

Comment: _“Unfortunately I can't see covers before around Feb 2013”_ - surprised you’re even getting those, because access to events is not possible any more for normal 3rd-party apps according to documentation, only to white-listed apps.

Comment: I'm using facebooks Graph API explorer

Comment: That is just a tool to make requests, you still need to use that with some app id of yours. Anyway, the Graph API is not very good when it comes to “historical” data, once you go back more than a couple of weeks or maybe months, you usually see stuff like this happen. _“but I fear the images are lost forever”_ - well, Facebook was not supposed to be your replacement of a proper backup of important files on your end to begin with … But maybe you could still find the necessary info, if you download all your data from Facebook? (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=your_facebook_information)

Comment: Actually, facebook is always going on about "memories", one of its main assets seems to be as a historical archive. I looked in actual events and the images are missing there too.